# How to backup and restore sql database when I clicked netbeans jbutton

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I want to know how to make this function,
when i want to backup my database in my program just one click database should save the document and  when i click restore button it should be restored the database automatically.

My programmed design by jFrame
this is the main interface code

```
package bankapplication;
```

public class MainInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public MainInterface() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setIcon();

    }
}
```

If you know,how to solve this problem please help me to do that.
Thanks..

Comment: I noticed you're new here. You may want to explain to us what you've tried rather than just asking us to do this for you. Stack Overflow's about helping you, but first you need to take a stab at the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.Runtime.exec(String command)` method executes the specified `string command` in a separate process
you can `import and export mysql database` by using the following query

backup: # `mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`

restore:# `mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql`

what im doing with my program is executing the above query using  java runtime.
query i've created :- `"mysqldump -u " + "root" + " -p" + "password" + " databasename -r " + javaPath"`
replace the `password` with your password and replace `databasename` with your databasename and try the code
and let us know the errors you got after that.

```
    execute a back up
                    public void executeBackUp(){
                    try {
                        String javaPath = "filePath";
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u " + "root" + " -p" + "password" + " databasename -r " + javaPath);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Backup File Created.", "Done", 1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }

    restore a backup                
                    public void restore(){
    try {
                    String path = "filepath";
                    String arrayCommand[] = new String[]{"mysql", "databasename", "-u", "root", "-p" + "password", "-e", " source " + path};
                    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayCommand);
                    int processStatus = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
                    if (processStatus == 1) {
                        System.out.println("failed");
                    } else if (processStatus == 0) {
                        System.out.println("success");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping my truble

Comment: Thanks for helping my trouble,I'm beginner for java programmer..So I don't no what is the                                                                                            filePath  -                                                                                                    mysqldump -u                                                                                                root                                                                                                                    -p  & javaPath Please Intorduce of these clearly. It is healpful for me Thanks

Comment: file path in the backup method is the place you want the backup saved.
fie path in the restore method is the place where your database back file stored,

Comment: a code is written 
mysqldump -u " + "root" + " -p" + "password" + " databasename -r " + javaPath like this and it will be executed by java. password is the mysql
password , databasename is the name of your database.

Comment: Thanks for helping me..please give me a sample of this backup code..I don't understand   -u " + "root" + " -p"  please tell me what is this..I thank you again for helping beginner of java like me....

Comment: sample query `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u " + "root" + " -p" + "123" + " inventory -r " + javaPath);`

Comment: Please tell me what is the meaning of -u / "root / " -p"

Comment: -u is for user name and -p is for password

Comment: u realize that its a command im executing using java and yet u are asking what is -u and what is -p seriously. for the last time its a commandline to backup and restore database.you dont have to ask what is -u and what is -p

Comment: and what do you mean by give a sample of my code i have already given you 2 methods to import and export database files, just call them from a button.